# using openpyxl write a large matrix into excel, it throw a memery error

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
These days I use the openpyxl to write the large excel data.
```

The data contains 3000 rows and 3000 cols. I use openpyxl's [optimized writer](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html#optimized-writer) to write this large matrix into excel, but it throws memeory error. 
The detail of my write excel funtion as follow:

```
def write_xlsx_file(paths):
   file_name = 'statis_block_base_info_.xlsx'
   #print 'write the ' + str(month) + ' file:' + file_name

    wb = Workbook(write_only = True)

    path_ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
    path_ws.title = 'path_links'

    paths_row = len(paths)
    for i in xrange(0, paths_row):
       path_ws.append(paths[i])

    wb.save(file_name)
```

Comment: Do you really need excel? What if you write it as a csv that you can later import into excel?

Comment: Excel can't handle 90000 columns. Pre excel-2007, the max number of columns used to be 256. in Excel 2010 they changed it to ~16000 columns, which I believe is still the max number. Perhaps you should look at another program to examine this data in, because even if you save it as a text file, excel will not be able to handle it.

Comment: According to the [XLS file format specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.12).aspx): `The maximum row index is 65535. The maximum column index is 255.` so I believe @HaleemurAli is correct.

Comment: @HaleemurAli,I am sorry, I make a mistake. The matrix is 3000*3000.But you answer is right, I search it before I asked this question.

Comment: @average,Excel 1997 and Excel 2003， the max col is  256 and row is 65,536.But in  2010 and  Excel 2007, the max of col is 16384 and row is 1,048,576 . In the morning, the run it again, it throw IOError. But I use the function to write two sheet contained a matrix 2160*2160 ,it work correctly.

Comment: @average openpyxl only writes xlsx files. Taking guesses about the specification limit are not helpful.

openpyxl does enforce the column width limit but will happily write millions of rows. As xlsx is often just used as a data transfer format this is fine. Also, because the file format supports data typing it has advantages over plain text files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a memory error then this probably means that your worksheet has a lot of unique strings in it. In write-only mode openpyxl serialises each row as it goes and 3000 cells do not use a lot of memory. However, strings are kept in a central dictionary that cannot be serialised until all cells have been written. But this should only be the case where you have a different string in virtually every cell. If this is the case then the only solution with openpyxl is more memory.

Does this describe your situation? How much memory is in use? Other libraries such as xlsxwriter have a way around this by serialising strings directly as child objects. So you might want to give that a try using "constant memory" mode.

Comment: ,I just write the integers into cell, so I guess all of the memery is about 36M. The afternoon of yesterday,I run the code again.It work correctly. The value of cell almost is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dump large amounts of data using openpyxl, only using `write_only=True` option will not help, as stated in openpyxl documentation, you need to install lxml.

For me, memory consumption reduced from over 4GB to less than 100MB after installing lxml

openpyxl documentation (search for lxml and you will find the suggestion): https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html

for installing lxml using pip:

```
pip install lxml
```